# Store first referring URL in one variable along with $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] in another

Tags: php, http-referer

I'm using the two functions below to store referrer information in variables which are inserted into a form email body. I need to store the first referring site or URL in one variable and the normal referring URL in another. Basically I need to get the first page or search engine which has referred a visitor, then store the very last page on my site they visited before coming to the contact form. The second part works with the first function getting the HTTP_REFERRER. But my function (function getFirstPage) to get the original referrer is just sending the contact page URL to me in the variable.

```
function getRefererPage( $form_tag )
{
        if ( $form_tag['name'] == 'referer-page' ) {
                $form_tag['values'][] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        }
        return $form_tag;
}
function getFirstPage( $form_tag )
{
session_start();
        if (!isset($_SESSION["origURL"]))
            $_SESSION["origURL"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];

        if ( $form_tag['name'] == 'first-page' ) {
            $form_tag['values'][] = $_SESSION["origURL"];
        }
        return $form_tag;
}
if ( !is_admin() ) {
        add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_tag', 'getRefererPage' );
}
if ( !is_admin() ) {
        add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_tag', 'getFirstPage' );
}
```

What can I change to get the original referrer into my function getFirstPage?

Comment: @njk I'm not sure how to store the original referring URL in one variable and still user HTTP_REFERRER in another

Comment: This is not going to work if you have SEO urls or a big site with multiply php files.

I recommend to write an function to check if user entered your site for first time in last 20 minute for example and save referring page in a cookie then use it where you want.

Comment: @SoroushFalahati that sounds ideal i've edited the question since I think I almost have it working. I'm just not too good with php to do what you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this code in all of your pages (Or in a PHP file that is included in all other pages. If using a framework or CMS you can put it in your index.php). This code will save ref page for first time after 20min of inactivity. Mean almost any time someone open your website.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['firstPageRef'])){
    setcookie('firstPageRef', $_COOKIE['firstPageRef'], time() + 1200); // Extend for an other 20Min
}else{
    setcookie('firstPageRef', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], time() + 1200); // Save ref page for first time
}
```

Then using this code you can find out which site redirected users to your website:
call it when you need it:

```
function GetFirstRef(){
    if (isset($_COOKIE['firstPageRef'])
        return $_COOKIE['firstPageRef'];
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I put the if condition in my footer but it's breaking the page and isn't loading the footer anymore. Any suggestions?

Comment: There was a missing ) before end of condition. Please try again. I wrote this code here so this type of problems occurs. Sorry/

Comment: I'm not seeing any cookie set as the first referring page

Comment: @Anagio, Maybe because you opened your website by directly opening it from address bar or bookmarks?! Remove cookies and open your web site from an other website. Any way tested and works as expected. You may need to see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I'm running searches in Google with instant search disabled

Comment: @Anagio What is your website?! Can you tel me?! Any link or something?